# Having a two language website

Tags: multi-language, language

I want to have a English and Persian website, as you know English is **right to left** and Persian is **left to right**. When I post something and set my WordPress to English, all the site and all posts will move to left to right.

But this is my personal website and I want sometime post in English and sometimes post in Persian, and editor do not allow me to change direction, it just has text-align **(css:direction:rtl or direction:ltr)**

How can I change each post direction?

Is there any other way?

Comment: what's the default language of your blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Convert](http://make.marketpress.com/multilingualpress/2014/02/how-to-install-multi-site/) your site to a multisite, then …

1. Create a second site. Set the site language to Persian in *Options/General*.
2. Set the language of the first site to English.
3. You can install a plugin to link translated posts like [MultilingualPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/) (disclosure: I was the lead developer for that plugin for a long time).
4. You can customize the Persian site now to handle RTL content better, for example with a dedicated [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of the main theme and special plugins.

The post editor will now work automatically without further customization.